How can I create a public link for a content folder via Apex that opens the folder in Salesforce Lightning Experience?
I was trying to generate public link for  content folder inside one of my library via apex.
I am using following code snippet from anonymous window:-
String folderUrl = URL.getOrgDomainURL().toExternalForm() + '/' + ‘contentFolderId’;
System.debug(folderUrl);
Above code is providing me a url. When I am using that url I am getting landed in classic even I am working in lightning. Can you please explain me the reason behind this.
I tried different things like content distribution, content version but I didn’t get any lead. I also tried {NavigationMixin } from "lightning/navigation" in lwc it is woking fine for files but when I am using it for folders it redirecting me to the page where I am getting following message:-
“This list view isn't available in Lightning Experience. To see this list view, use Salesforce Classic or switch to another list view”.
I also tried to create contentDistribution but unable to generate public link for folder.
Please let me know if there is any possible way to generate public link via apex so that I can see that folder in lightning.
I know there is out of the box functionality to generate public link for content folder by clicking on button, I want to do same thing via Apex.
